# Django filters. is_safe doesn't work

Tags: python, django

In my app ***teams/templatetags/teams_extras.py*** I have this filter

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def quote(text):
    return "&laquo; {} &raquo;".format(text)
```

So I use it into my view ***teams/templates/teams/show.html***

```
{% extends './base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load teams_extras %}
...
<b>Bio :</b> {{ team.biography|quote }}
...
```

But this is the result on my page:

```
&laquo; <p>The Miami Heat are an American professional basketball team based in Miami. The Heat compete in the National Basketball Association as a member of the league's Eastern Conference Southeast Division</p> &raquo;
```

Why ?
Thank you

Comment: try this `return "« {} »".format(text)`

Comment: I have this: `« <p>The Miami Heat are an American professional basketball team based in Miami. The Heat compete in the National Basketball Association as a member of the league's Eastern Conference Southeast Division</p> »`

Comment: you can use the filter safe [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)

Comment: I know but is redundant...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doc [says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping):

> This flag tells Django that if a “safe” string is passed into your filter, the result will still be “safe” and if a non-safe string is passed in, Django will automatically escape it, if necessary.

So try to pass safe value into your filter:

```
{{ team.biography|safe|quote }}
```

or user [mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe):

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

@register.filter()
def quote(text):
    return mark_safe("&laquo; {} &raquo;".format(text))
```

And:

```
{{ team.biography|quote }}
```

This should works.